# marking scale between Egypt and the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, grades, education

How can I convert marks in the Egyptian scale to marks in the UK scale.
for example if I got a mark of 40 in Egypt what is the equivalent mark in the UK.

Comment: It's called _rule of three_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three

Comment: @PsySp: Are you sure that it's *that* easy? There's a whole page on Wikipedia dedicated to international grading systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grading_systems_by_country. I'm pretty certain that you can't simply convert between all of them by applying the rule of three. For example, the German grading system uses the grades 1.0 (best), 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, ... down to 5.0 (fail). Usually, in-between grades (e.g. 1.5) are not allowed. Most people treat the distance between (1.0 and 1.3) and (1.3 and 1.7) the same: as one subgrade unit. Can you model that by the rule of three?

Comment: @Schmuddi If both systems are modeled by a discrete scale with a discrete meaning, I do not see where is the problem.

Comment: @PsySp: German 1.0 corresponds to the 96-100 percent bracket, 1.3 to the 91-95 percent bracket, 1.7 to the 86-90 percent bracket, and so on. So, the German scale is increasing with decreasing percentages, and it is neither continuous nor are the steps equidistant.  Unless you have a mapping function, you cannot express this by the rule of three.

Comment: @Schmuddi It seems highly structured to me (96-100, 86-90 and so on) but I see your point and I agree.

Answer (score 5):

According to Naric (the UK's national agency responsible for grade comparisons):

> [Egyptian undergraduate] grading systems vary between institutions and even departments. The table below indicates the different systems in use and the relationship between them:
>
> `75-100     Distinguished / excellent / very good     A`
>
> `65-74      Good                                      B`
>
> `50-64      Pass                                      C`
>
> `0-49       Fail/Weak                                 F`

For a UK undegraduate degree, grading is almost always as follows

`70-100     First Class`

`60-69      Second Class Upper Division (often written 2.1)`

`50-59      Second Class Lower Division (often written 2.2)`

`40-49      Third Class`

`0-39       Fail`

Naric suggests the following equivalency:

First class = A or A-

Second Class Upper Division = B+ or B

Second Class Lower Division = B- or C+

Third Class = C